# How to tell that a java project build in eclipse succeeded?

Tags: java, eclipse

Using eclipse to build a java project, I hit the Build Project button, there is no discerneable feedback/output whatsoever?

How can I tell that a build, happend and succeeded?
I have looked that in the filesystem the Project directory has indeed a `/bin` directories with compiled `*.class` files, so I now that something was build, but I look for a way to have eclipse give me that information.

How to configure eclipse to give output (i.e. to the console, status bar, if necessary message popupbox) about that some building happend.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println("Ok.");`at the end of your main. This might be a little rude, but if you see any "Ok." in console, you will know that, even if it might not have done what you expected, your project has runned succesfully and entirely.

Comment: If Eclipse didn't tell you build failed, it means it succeeded

Comment: @Badda the main method is not executed during the build.

Comment: @dunni True. I misunderstood the question. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

As such you should get a popup window (*shown in my last screenshot*) showing the progress of your build, but in case if you are not getting then you can follow below steps to get **"Progress" view of the Eclipse which shows progress of everything in the Eclipse**.

[image]

[image]

And then build the project:

[image]

[image]

And you should get the progress information

[image]

---

As an aside: how to identify if Eclipse project has error? - If you project has build errors (it could be Java build problems, or JS or XML issues) then in the "Project Explorer" you will see a cross-mark-inside-red-square against that project, see a sample below:

[image]

---

**Update:** Another possibility to double check - make sure you are not running progress bars in the background, to verify that go to `Window --> Preferences --> General` and make sure "Always run in background" is NOT checked.

[image]

---

Further reading: [this](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/14/show-it-again-how-to-re-enable-hidden-dialogs-in-eclipse/)

Comment: thank you for the very nicely picture supplied answer. I tried to replicate it. Stuff is that with my eclipse neon setup it seems not to work, that is even though the progress view is added nothing happens in their.

Comment: Have you made sure that you are running in Java or JEE perspective?

Comment: I have added some updates, also there could be a possibility that your workspace code is too less so build is way too fast to be noticed, so better import JDK code or some other bigger code base in your workspace and try to build that.

Comment: if it was "too fast" (strange as eclipse is quite slow itself....), it could still log the build to the progress or history, or any log, right? I looked at IDEA and they log the build, even for very small builds. A build is noticible there, so something is wrong here with eclipse. I will check again

Comment: I checked also that I have the setting to "always run in background" NOT enabled. BTW, what is it that meant here?

Comment: It means operations like building, installing new plugins etc. will run in background.

Comment: Personally I don't feel eclipse is too slow, it just that how you need to manage that, but even if you feel it is slow you should try to do a build on a project with large code base and see what happens then. As an aside if you feel eclipse is slow then make sure you do not have lot of unnecessary plugins installed and active, also if you are using pure Java project then keep Java perspective instead of JEE, things like this can make a difference.